# New field on crystal report not showing on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have never worked on Crystal Reports before. Recently I had to make a small change in one of the existing report file. I had to add a new field on the report. I have verified the database, edited the SQL Query in report designer and can se the new field under DataBase Fields>Command. This works fine on my machine. However, when I publish my project and copy all the generated dlls the newly added field is not present on the production server. Whenever the report is run using aspx page, the report does not have that field. What do I need to upload on server apart from the generated dlls? Sorry for my naive enquiry but I have never worked with Crystal Reports.

Comment: Have you copied report on server (`.rpt` file)?

Comment: Thank you very much @KuKeC. You saved my day. but I don't understand, why .rpt files are not created in the output directory when I publish the project? Anyways, you can add it as an answer. I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Glad to help you. That .rpt file is separated file which is called from your program. It's not embedded into your c# code. That's why he isn't into your dlls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy .rpt file to server aswell.

That should do it.